# How can I evaluate a certain kind of summation?

Tags: summation

I have the following sum

[image]

`P0`, `P1` and `P2` are constants. The problem is to assign all possible values to `a`, `b`, `c` so their sum is always 33 and compute the sum.

`a`, `b`, `c` are all individually positive only.

Comment: All possible **positive integer** values, I assume? Or can `b, c` individually be negative?

Comment: Instead of screenshot, can you include the code directly into your post?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer likely `b` and `c` are not negative, lest the factorials in the denominator go to infinity.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: The problem is I dont have any code yet. I just want to solve it. #QuantumDot

Comment: a,b,c are all individually positive only. #Marius Ladegård Meyer

Answer (score 8):

```
Sum[Boole[a + b + c == 33 && ((a > 0 || a == 0) && (b + c) > 0)] 
           33!/(a! b! c!) p0^a p1^b p2^c,{a, 0, 33}, {b, 0, 33}, {c, 0, 33}]
```

But why bother with that, when

```
Probability[(a > 0 || a == 0) && (b + c) > 0, 
            {a, b, c} \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[33, {p0, p1, p2}]]
```

Suffices and is much more obvious.

Do note, I did not use your subscripted variables - in general, reserve that for display purposes.

Also, your condition of `(a > 0 || a == 0)` is a bit wonky - it's the same as `a>=0`, why not just use that?

Comment: probability to the rescue...while I was loitering with mulitnomials....+1::)

Comment: Yep, the multiple factorials in the denominator ought to have tipped people off. Another alternative: `Sum[(Multinomial @@ idx) Inner[Power, {p0, p1, p2}, idx, Times], {idx, FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, 33]}] - p0^33`.

Comment: @J.M. Oooh, FrobeniusSolve... *shiny*... +1

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption that b>=0,c>=0  (not both), then this reduces 0<=a<33 and c=33-b-a (which is >0 as a is strictly less than 33). So the sum is equivalent to:

```
(p1+p2+p3)^33-p1^3
```

If you wished to code the sum you could:

```
f[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
 Module[{ip = 
    Catenate@(Permutations /@ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[33, 3]]), mn,
    ps},
  mn = Multinomial @@@ ip;
  ps = p1^#1 p2^#2 p3^#3 & @@@ ip;
  Total[mn ps]-p1^3]
```

Note:

```
f[p1, p2, p3] == Expand[(p1 + p2 + p3)^33] - p1^33
```

yields `True`

Just for fun, assuming the p's sum to 1 (as theuse of letter  p suggests) and using ciao's answer:

```
pr[p0_, p1_, p2_] := 
 Probability[(a > 0 || a == 0) && (b + c) > 0, {a, b, 
    c} \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[33, {p0, p1, p2}]]
pr2[p0_, p1_, p2_] := 
 Probability[
  a < 33, {a, b, c} \[Distributed] 
   MultinomialDistribution[33, {p0, p1, p2}]]
```

then

```
pr[0.99, 0.005, 0.005] == pr2[0.99, 0.005, 0.005] == 
 f[0.99, 0.005, 0.005]
```

yields `True` (note it suffices just to use a<33) and the sum reduces to `1-p1^33`